# How to let closure compiler stop omitting object parameters?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I'm working with closure compiler. I've compiled a library with functions returning objects. The compiler said that the returning object is inconsistent.

```
~~~~x.js:52: ERROR - inconsistent return type
found   : {a: number, b: number, c: number, d: number, ...}
required: {a: number, b: number, c: number, d: number, ...}
```

I can't find out what's different ...

Are there any options to show what's omitted in `...`?

Comment: I don't think there are. Could you submit an issue at https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/issues/list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't currently an option; we really should do a better job showing the differences in record types.  You can, however, narrow down the issue by doing something like:

```
var y = problemValue;
/** @type {ExpectedType} */
var x = /** @type {ExpectedType} */({});

// check each property
x.a = y.a;
x.b = y.b;
```

In most cases, this will show you property that is not assignable and causing the problem.